# Python install of setup.py files not running 2to3

Tags: python, pyglet, python-2to3

Recently, when trying to install the pyglet module for openGL in python, I have run into a problem.  It appears that when running a setup.py file, it is not converted with 2to3.  Due to this issue, I am unable to use pyglet in python 3 due to errors from the python 2 code contained in pyglet.  Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [1.2alpha1](http://www.pyglet.org/download.html) release, which has Python 3 support.